# How can I create a class instance(s) to show all rows of content from my web scraper?

Tags: python

Created a class "Product" and properly instantiated. I'm trying to show all items from the webpage, but only the last item in the list comes up. What can I do to create objects that can show all instances of "productName" and "productRating"?

```
class Product:
    def __init__(self, productName, productRating):
        self.productName = productName
        self.productRating = productRating

    def showProduct(self):
        print("Product Name:    " + self.productName)
        print("Rating:  " + self.productRating)

productList = []

productInfo = browser.find_elements_by_css_selector(".sg-col-12-of-20")

for data in productInfo:
    textContent = data.get_attribute('innerHTML')
    soup = BeautifulSoup(textContent, features="lxml")
    rawString = soup.get_text().strip()
    clean = rawString.split('*')
    row1 = 0
    row2 = 1
    productName = clean[row1]
    productRating = clean[row2]


    productEvent1 = Product(productName, productRating)
productList.append(productEvent1)

for Product in productList:
    Product.showProduct()
    print("\n")
```

Comment: The indentation for the command `productList.append(productEvent1)` is not correct (currently not part of the for loop), is it an error in your post or from your source code? Just to be sure ;-)

Comment: It is deliberately not part of the for loop . My instructor said it should be outside when I asked. Should it be inside the loop?

Comment: You should try, but in my opinion, it's the reason why you have only the latest item

Comment: I agree with @Christophe - `append()` should be inside `for`-loop and it should resolve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

You need to integrate this line `productList.append(productEvent1)` in the loop.
The reason is that in **each** loop, you calculate `productEvent1` and append **each** value to your list. If its out of the loop, you will just have the latest value and only 1 item in your list.

The code should be like this:

```py
for data in productInfo:
    textContent = data.get_attribute('innerHTML')
    soup = BeautifulSoup(textContent, features="lxml")
    rawString = soup.get_text().strip()
    clean = rawString.split('*')
    row1 = 0
    row2 = 1
    productName = clean[row1]
    productRating = clean[row2]


    productEvent1 = Product(productName, productRating)
    productList.append(productEvent1)
```